# why the deleted records still existing

Tags: java, hibernate

in the below list there are 39 entries. the first 35 entries were inserted into the database table through hibernate class TestAuthor. After inserting the first 34 record I deleted all of them from the table TestAuthor from the 
database. Then i inserted the last 5 records in the database and implemented the method showAllInTestAuthor which posted belwo. When i called the method showAllInTestAuthor, i expected it to display only the last 5 records

```
Ali, gamil 48
Fatma, Joss 49
Lobna, Nolan 50
Ahmed, Ghadi 51
Nour, Youssri 52
```

but actually it displayed all the entries shown below.
Why that method displayed all these entries while the entries with id from 1 up tp 47 were deleted

**entries displayed**:

```
//fName, lName, ID
Frank, Diem 1
Amr, Bakri 2
Amr, Bakri 6
Amr, Bakri 9
Alan, dier 11
Fatma, Joss 13
Fatma, Joss 16
Nour, Youssri 26
Nour, Youssri 27
Ali, gamil 28
Ali, gamil 38
Fatma, Joss 39
Lobna, Nolan 40
Ahmed, Ghadi 41
Nour, Youssri 42
Ali, gamil 53
Fatma, Joss 54
Lobna, Nolan 55
Ahmed, Ghadi 56
Nour, Youssri 57
Nour, Youssri 29
Nour, Youssri 30
Nour, Youssri 31
Nour, Youssri 32
Ali, gamil 33
Fatma, Joss 34
Lobna, Nolan 35
Ahmed, Ghadi 36
Nour, Youssri 37
Ali, gamil 43
Fatma, Joss 44
Lobna, Nolan 45
Ahmed, Ghadi 46
Nour, Youssri 47
Ali, gamil 48
Fatma, Joss 49
Lobna, Nolan 50
Ahmed, Ghadi 51
Nour, Youssri 52
```

**showAllInTestAuthor**:

```
private void showAllInTestAuthor() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for (TestAuthor author : (List<TestAuthor>) HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("SELECT * from afk_owner.TESTAUTHOR").addEntity(TestAuthor.class).list()) {

        System.out.println(author.getmFName() + ", " + author.getmLName() + " " + (author.getmAuthorID()));
    }
}
```

**deletion command**

```
delete from TESTAUTHOR;
```

**insertion command**:

```
TestAuthor testAuthor = new TestAuthor();
    testAuthor.setmFName("Ali");
    testAuthor.setmLName("gamil");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);

    testAuthor = new TestAuthor();
    testAuthor.setmFName("Fatma");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Joss");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);

    testAuthor = new TestAuthor();
    testAuthor.setmFName("Lobna");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Nolan");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);

    testAuthor = new TestAuthor();
    testAuthor.setmFName("Ahmed");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Ghadi");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);

    testAuthor = new TestAuthor();
    testAuthor.setmFName("Nour");
    testAuthor.setmLName("Youssri");
    HibernateUtil.getCurrentSession().persist(testAuthor);

    showAllInTestAuthor();
```

Comment: Show your insert and delete code.

Comment: My guess is that you never flushed your Hibernate session after deleting, which means the records were never actually deleted from the database.  But since you left out that relevant code, I cannot be sure.

Comment: Hibernate manages a cache. Removing rows from the underlying database has no immediate effect on that cache.

Comment: The insertion and deletion code may be at fault here, so you should probably show it as well.

Comment: @talex please see it above

Comment: @user2121 please post your code where you are deleting

Comment: How do you execute `delete from TESTAUTHOR`? It looks like you do it behind Hibernate back.

Comment: @talex i ran that command in OracleSQL Developer

Comment: @user2121 You doing it while hibernate transaction is opened? If so Hibernate do not expect it and may recreate records that it have in cache.

Comment: @talex actually i solved it by COMMIT WORK command in ORACLESQLDeveloper...when i deleteed the rows i COMMIT and then add the last 5 rows mentioned above..and when i use SELECT command to display the contents, it displayed now only the records i inserted it